# Android studio how to unchecked v2 full apk signature?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to sign the apk from my android studio, the problem is the signing of the apk have the V2 (full apk signature) checked and cannot uncheck it.
It is disabled
i am using

```
     compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" [![see][1]][1]
```

Comment: check the usual signature with java. Then you can uncheck v2 signature...you have to select one of them...

Comment: the both are disabled !!

Comment: then I guess your certificate has expired or it isn´t available on the path you have set in Adnroid Studio. See here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

The signature verification V2 was introduced in Android Nougat. So only if its android nougat compatible, bothe the options will be shown.Please upgrade your compilesdkverion to 24.For more details refer [link](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/)

Comment: it is 25 now and same problem cannot check or uncheck any one

Comment: what is your buildtoolsversion?

Comment: @Amalo try making it to the latest. (25.0.0)

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"